# How to parse a certain column from a certain line in an ASCII file?

Tags: python, parsing, ascii

I am trying to parse out a string value from a certain column in a certain line in my ASCII file. Below I have included what I have tried to this point, the error I received when I ran this code is:

```
Attribute: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = open('zz_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012021505HP001.Hdr', 'r')

line = f.readlines(49)
columns = line.split()
time = columns(2)
print (time)

f.close()
```

Comment: Lists do not have a `.split()` function. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a function to do it.
 
Note that line and column number are counted from 1, not zero.

```
def find_line_and_column(filename, line_num, column_num):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for i in range(line_num-1):  # skip over lines before the desired one
            next(file)
        line = next(file)  # read the desired line
        return line.split()[column_num-1]

# sample usage
print(find_line_and_column('zz_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012021505HP001.Hdr', 4, 3))
```

Alternatively, using the [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) function in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module would allow it to be done a little bit more succinctly:

```
import itertools

def find_line_and_column(filename, line_num, column_num):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        line = next(itertools.islice(file, line_num-1, None), None) # get line_num-th line
        return line.split()[column_num-1]
```